# How to eliminate spurious/superfluous spaces within a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, string, foreach

This code:

```
const string LabelToFind = "goTo considered Harmful";
using (var file = new StreamReader(DownloadedFile))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null) {
        if ((line.Contains(keyVal)) && (line.Contains(LabelToFind))) {
            string[] logLineElements = line.Split('|'); 
            foreach (string element in logLineElements) {
                if (element.Contains(LabelToFind)) {
                    return element.Substring(element.IndexOf(LabelToFind, StringComparison.Ordinal) + LabelToFind.Length, element.Length - LabelToFind.Length);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

...fails with "Argument Out of Range Exception: Index and length must refer to a location within the string.
Parameter name: length" when "element" has a leading and trailing space (which it always does). I guess I could do this:

```
foreach (string element in logLineElements) {
    if (element.Contains(LabelToFind)) {
        String s = element.Trim();
        return s.Substring(s.IndexOf(LabelToFind, StringComparison.Ordinal) + LabelToFind.Length, s.Length - LabelToFind.Length);
```

...but it doesn't smell right...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split and trim same time before the foreach.

```
List<string> logLineElements = line.Split('|').Select(e => e.Trim()).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

In taking the substring, you're starting at the character after the first instance of your `LabelToFind`, but for the length parameter you are using simply the original length of the `element`, minus the length of `LabelToFind`. If the string is found anywhere other than the start of `element` (which you suggest is always the case), this will fail, because you're trying to take more characters than remain in the string.

Assuming you want to return the string after `LabelToFind`, which is what your code would appear to be trying to do, try:

```
const string LabelToFind = "goTo considered Harmful";
using (var file = new StreamReader(DownloadedFile))
{
    string line;
    while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (line.Contains(keyVal) && line.Contains(LabelToFind))
        {
            foreach (var element in line.Split('|'))
            {
                var index = element.IndexOf(LabelToFind, StringComparison.Ordinal);
                if (index != -1)
                {
                    return element.Substring(index + LabelToFind.Length, element.Length - LabelToFind.Length - index).Trim();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know; I'm wondering if there's a better way to trim that "element" than the way I'm doing it. It works, but it reeks rather rancidly.

Comment: It's rather unclear what you're actually trying to achieve. It would appear that you are trying to get all the text after LabelToFind in the element (and I've edited my answer to add the code you could use do to this). Is that not the case?

Comment: yes. If the line is " goTo considered Harmful SitOnASpudBucketOtis " I want "SitOnASpudBucketOtis"

Comment: I've edited my answer to do this, adding a Trim() of the output before returning (which will remove any trailing spaces, as well as any spaces that were between LabelToFind and the rest of the string).